# WPF Custom UserControl as a RadioToggleButton

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, controltemplate

I've created a custom UserControl that functions like a RadioButton but looks like a Toggle Button. The only issue I'm having is being able to set the Content property of the UserControl and have it appear in the ToggleButton. Here's what I've tried:

```
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton>
                <RadioButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </RadioButton.Template>
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
```

When I try to build this, I get the error: "Cannot find the static member 'ContentProperty' on the type 'Control'." I've been hung up on this all morning, and while I've tried to mimic a few examples, so far nothing has done the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
<UserControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton Content="{TemplateBinding UserControl.Content}">
            <RadioButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding UserControl.Content}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RadioButton.Template>
        </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: The alternative is to specify the `TargetType` attribute on your `DataTemplate`.